# prove that this expression converges in probability to zero

Tags: probability, random-variable, convergence, unit-root

Apparently $T^{-3/2} \sum\limits_{t=1}^T{y_{t-1}}u_t$ converges by law to $0.5\times T^{-1/2}\sigma^2 (X-1)$, where $X$ is a $\chi^2(1)$ random variable. $u_t$ is white noise and $y_t$ is an **AR(1)** process, that is $y_t=y_{t-1}+u_t$ with $u_t\sim iid N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I want to prove that the above expression also **converges in probability to zero**.

Now it appears the variance of this expression is of order $1/T$. I deduct this by noting that the variance of a a $\chi^2$ variable is finite and we have something finite divided by $\sqrt{T}$. This implies that the variance of the whole expression converges to zero. If I am not mistaken, this then also implies that the above expression converges in probability to its mean (?)

Now am a little unsure now how to obtain the mean of this assymptotic expression.

To prove  $0.5\times T^{-1/2}\sigma^2 (X-1)$ converges in probability to zero, can I simply take the expectation this expression by assumging that the expecation of a $\chi^2(n)$ variable is $n$? That would be then $0.5\times T^{-1/2}\sigma^2 (1-1)=0$. Therefore we have $0.5\times T^{-1/2}\sigma^2 (X-1)\rightarrow_p0$? Is this rigorous enough?

Comment: This question appears to lack essential information. (1) What is the relationship between $u_t$ and $y_t$? (2) It makes no sense to have anything depending on $T$ in the expression after "converges to": the convergence is independent of $T$. You might just as well multiply both sides by $T^{1/2}$. (3) Where does $\sigma^2$ come from?

Comment: The relationship between $y_t$ and $u_t$ is given by the information, that we have an AR(1) process with unit root, that is $y_t=y_{t-1}+u_t$. Convergence here means with time series, that T goes to infinity. The above expression is a standard expression for superconsitency of a random walk, in particular, to derive the t distribution of a unit root process. See for example, Hamilton p.488.

Comment: There's something wrong here: your statement is mathematically meaningless.  As $T\to \infty$, then necessarily $0.5T^{-1/2}\sigma^2(X-1) \to 0$.  Is $\sigma^2$ the common variance of $u_t$?

Comment: No, the above expression converges to a Brownian Motion functional, that is, it converges asymptotically in distribution by the functional central limit theorem. Yes, $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $u_t$. You can think of this as when we scale by $T^{-1} \sum\limits_{t=1}^T{y_{t-1}}u_t$ it converges to $0.5 \sigma^2 [[W(1)]^2-1]$ You can apply the functional limit theorem together with the continuous mapping theorem, hence it is correct to say it converges to something that is divided by T. This literally taken from Hamilton, p. 488 as leading example for the derivative of the unit root dist.

Comment: At least Hamilton expresses it like this... Which then results in the conclusion that the variance degenerates to zero, as the part that converges to a functional expressed by a brownian motion has a finite variance. My point is however not to question Hamiltonian semantics, but how to arrive to the convergence in probability to a mean of zero

Comment: I see that this indeed is one way to express something that Hamilton actually wrote. It's still nonsense! I'm not talking about mere "semantics," either: if a statement makes no mathematical sense, we have to work to understand it and that risks miscommunication. He refers to Proposition 17.1(b), in which $T^{-1/2}$ does not appear on the right hand side, so apparently this quotation is a sloppy way of saying that the left hand side gets close to the right hand side for large $T$. Indeed, in the text he is making exactly such a $O(1/T)$ argument.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it over a long bus ride home.. maybe you are right. It's mathematical nonsense, but Hamilton perhaps meant to say: since the right part converges towards a RV with a constant variance and by the power of the continuous mapping theorem, the left hand part dominates and thus the variance of the potential whole expression converges to zero... Whatever he meant to say, the question remains, why does the whole thing converge in probability to zero?

Comment: I don't know how to rephrase the question. I guess Hamilton had the same problem after all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the standard random-walk model

$$y_t = \rho y_{t-1} + u_t,\;\; y_0=u_0=0$$ and a sample of $T$ observations on $y$.

Under the null hypothesis that $\rho =1$, we have

$$y_t^2 = (y_{t-1} + u_t)^2 = y_{t-1}^2 + 2y_{t-1}u_t + u_t^2$$

$$\Rightarrow y_{t-1}u_t  =\frac 12(y_t^2-y_{t-1}^2-u_t^2)$$

Summing over $T$ we obtain

$$\sum_{t=1}^T{y_{t-1}}u_t = \frac 12 (y_T^2 - y_0^2) - \frac 12\sum_{t=1}^Tu_t^2=\frac 12 y_T^2 - \frac 12\sum_{t=1}^Tu_t^2$$

Divide both sides by $\sigma^2T$ and manipulate to obtain

$$\frac 1{\sigma^2T}\sum_{t=1}^T{y_{t-1}}u_t = \frac 1{2} \left(\frac{y_T}{\sigma\sqrt T}\right)^2 - \frac 1{2\sigma^2T}\sum_{t=1}^Tu_t^2$$

Since under $\rho=1$ we have $y_T = \sum_{t=1}^Tu_t$, $y_T$ is a normal random variable with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2T$. So, as an *exact* result, $\left(\frac{y_T}{\sigma\sqrt T}\right)^2$ is a chi-square with one degree of freedom, and this does *not* depend on the sample size. Call this random variable $Z$. Divide both sides further by $\sqrt T$ and re-arrange to obtain

$$\frac 1{T^{3/2}}\sum_{t=1}^T{y_{t-1}}u_t = \frac {\sigma^2}{2\sqrt{T}}Z - \frac 1{2T^{3/2}}\sum_{t=1}^Tu_t^2$$

Convergence to zero in probability means that the following must hold

$$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\text {Pr}\left(\Big|\frac {\sigma^2}{2\sqrt{T}}Z - \frac 1{2T^{3/2}}\sum_{t=1}^Tu_t^2\Big|>\epsilon\right) =0, \;\; \forall \epsilon >0$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\text {Pr}\left(\Big|\frac {\sigma^2}{2}Z - \frac 1{2T}\sum_{t=1}^Tu_t^2\Big|>\sqrt T\epsilon\right) =0$$

$\frac {\sigma^2}{2}Z$ remains finite as $T\rightarrow \infty$ since $Z$ remains a chi-square with one d.f. (hence finite variance). Also, $\frac 1{2T}\sum_{t=1}^Tu_t^2$ goes to $(1/2)\sigma^2$, so over all the absolute value goes to a finite quantity, while the term $\sqrt T\epsilon$ explodes. Therefore the limit of the probability of this event is indeed zero, and convergence in probability is established.

Note that this is the quantity for which you want to establish a zero plim, not for its limiting distribution.

Comment: Wow, this seems really rigid and elegantly avoids the argument about convergence in distribution! However, do you think that one could also argue the way I presented it at first within my question, that is, the variance converges to zero and this exceptionally implies convergence in probability since the expected value appears to be zero? OR do you think this is a bit too dodgy to argue like that?

Comment: I do not consider myself an expert in Asymptotics, but I believe that the particular application of the continuous mapping theorem by Hamilton is wrong (the application in the first sentence of your post). Essentially, Hamilton uses $T^{-1/2}$ as the "$g$" function of the continuous mapping theorem. But in all statements I have seen of this theorem, they always mention that _$g$ must not depend on the index that goes to infinity_, in order for the theorem to hold. So I wouldn't feel comfortable with working with this "limiting distribution". But even if I am wrong and Hamilton is right (CONTD)

Comment: (CONTD) ...then, in what sense a quantity that it is a non-trivial random variable at the limit of the index, also converges to zero at the limit of this index, and in a stronger mode of convergence? Again, I cannot see how this could hold, so I still believe that Hamilton proved a (correct) result, using a mistaken argument.

Comment: See also this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518736/delta-method-with-uniformly-convergent-transformation/520485#520485. It is tangential, but it shows a case where the composition of two functions that both depend on the index, does not necessarily converge even though each function separately does converge.

Comment: Without arguing for or against Hamilton, he does not touch upon the idea that the random variable goes to zero. He essentially says that the expressions total variance must be of order 1/T. I had the very same problem with that as this was for my limited understanding a bit too much and hence I asked it here on stackexchange. But I am glad you clarified this now.

Comment: Note for example p.486 that the standard asymptotic property $T^{-5/2}\sum{ty_{t-1}}\rightarrow_L \sigma \int rW(r)dr$ where $r$ is defined as $t/T$. Here, again we use the continuous mapping theorem, however, "T" is shoved within an integral. Having taken the limit of T, how does this make mathematically sense?

Comment: What Hamilton asserts appears in [17.1.15] and is referenced in Proposition 17.1(b): "$[1/(\sigma^2 T)]\sum_{t=1}^T y_{t-1}u_t \to (1/2)(X-1)$ where $X \sim\chi^2(1).$"  The arrow denotes convergence in distribution.  This *does* make sense.  Moreover, it immediately implies that when you multiply the left hand side by any function of $T$ converging to $0$, such as $T^{-1/2},$ you obtain $0$ in probability.  The argument appearing in [17.1.7] through [17.1.15] is practically identical to the one offered here by Alecos.

Comment: @whuber: I am talking about $T^{-5/2}\sum{ty_{t-1}}\rightarrow_L \sigma \int rW(r)dr$ where $r=t/T$. T is thus implicit on the right hand side, although less ostensible as in the question in consideration.

Comment: I am not talking about that: I am commenting on your question and on the current answer. Your previous two comments do not make any mathematical sense: there is no $t/T$ "implicit" in the right hand side.  Indeed, there is no $T$ whatsoever in *either* side, because "$T$" is a bound dummy variable.  But these issues are beside the point because they do not respond to (or clarify) your original question.

Comment: @whuber: What Alecos is saying that you cannot combine $g\times(1/2)(X-1)$ where g is $T^{-1/2}$ by using the continuous mapping theorem. That is why he is offering another way out in his solution. Nevertheless, when we use the continuous mapping theorem, like in the side example case two comments earlier, we use as our"g" within a composite expression, $r=t/T$. I am merely pointing out that you can use the continuous mapping theorem and an implicit if we leave it within the integral. So they are limited applications to that. I was responding to Alecos long comment at the beginning.